# why iframe can't show HTML file from another ROOT?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I use ASP.net C# , and i have an iframe and should fill it with a html Page from another root (outside my project root) with this code :

```
ContainFrame.Attributes["src"] = pageurl;
```

when i set an HTML path that inside in my project path into iframe (**for example : C:\JamMapped\people_Jam\test.aspx**) it works correctly but when i set address with another path outside my project (for example :**C:\JamMapped\Main_Jam\Files\ScormFiles\test.htm** ) it doesn't display anything ! why can i do for this problem ?

my project address is in : 
**C:\JamMapped\people_Jam\Themp.aspx**

and also my project is : **http:://localhost:3641/People_Jam/Jam.aspx**

and my HTML file is in :
**C:\JamMapped\Main_Jam\Files\ScormFiles\test.htm**

my this section code is :

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../../").Substring(0, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../../").Length - 1);
path = path.Substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\\"));
string pageurl = path + @"\Main_Jam\Files\ScormFiles\" + ClassID.ToString() + "\\" + TempLink.CommandName;
 ContainFrame.Attributes["src"] = pageurl;
```

i Use V.S 2005 . do you know why this code doesn't wok for outside path ? also for test i read content of this path HTML with stream reader and i understand my address is current but just iframe cant display it !

Comment: you have to set the virtual path... I think "../Main_Jam/Files/ScormFiles/test.htm" should do it for the url

Comment: i cant access to the parent path from root of Site ! can i ?
my project path is in "C:\JamMapped\**\people_Jam\**" and my required path is C:\JamMapped ! i think i cant access to previous level from my site root !

Comment: That is what the ../ is for. What I said should translate to "http://localhost:3641/Main_Jam/Files/ScormFiles/test.htm" which should be the url of the file. If you can't access it than the folder is not on the IIS and cannot be accessed in any way.

Comment: Dear friend "Main_Jam" doesn't add to my project ! you know ?
"localhost:3641/Main_Jam did not declare in IIS !

Comment: Are you using IIS on VS?, and which version?

Comment: no i just make an example ! i Use V.S 2005 . do you know why this code doesn't wok for  outside path ? also for test i read content of this path HTML with stream reader and i understand my address  is current but just iframe cant display it !

Comment: The problem you have is that the file isn't hosted, and for security reasons, you cannot access files which are not in the sandbox.

Comment: what is sandbox ? and is there any alternative way to solve this problem ?

Comment: A sandbox is a closed environment. The alternative is to simple host it somewhere. You cannot turn the sandbox off, there is an immense security risk if you do.